# Re-initialise Dropbox headless cli

Tags: dropbox

I'm running the headless Dropbox CLI on a linux EC2 VM, works fine.  I have created an AMI from my VM and created a new instance.  Dropbox CLI starts and reports syncing, but it's not syncing.  I suspect I need to re-initialise the client to create a new context between it and my account for this instance but I can't find any documentation on how to do that.  I probably just need to remove a file and restart the client, but what file?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `~/.dropbox`

Taken from this advanced reinstall guide for desktop: https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/advanced-reinstall